# Show Full Directory Path in Sharepoint 2010 Foundations

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, library

We recently migrated all of our SP sites from WSS 3.0 over to 2010 Foundations
One of our users is requesting the ability to see the full directory within the site that she is on it was that was in Wss 3.0 and now I am not sure how to make it work in 2010

The site will not let me post pics of what i am referring to but can provide if anyone can assist.

In WSS 3 it showed the directory path where you were in 2010 it's cutting it off..

Any advice..

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint 2010 has the ["Navigate Up" control](http://www.endusersharepoint.com/EUSP2010/2010/05/21/navigating-sharepoint-2010-part-1-introductions/) that appears as a folder icon next to the Site Actions menu and this provides access to the full current path.  However, don't get too comfortable with this as SharePoint 2013 then takes it away again and offers no direct replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Full breadcrumb path on **SharePoint 2010**:
https://fullpathbreadcrumb.codeplex.com/
[image: full breadcrumb SP2010]

Full breadcrumb path on **SharePoint 2013** by deploying designated `FolderNavigation.js` script in MasterPage:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-2013-Folder-661709eb
[image: full breadcrumb SP2013]

Answer (score 0):

If you have SharePoint Designer, this becomes trivial:

- Open SharePoint designer. Open the site you have the document list in.
- Select the View you want to use
- Click the "Add/Remove Columns" button. This will give you a list of columns you can add.
- Add "Path"
- Save; Done.

Why is this column accessible only in SharePoint Designer and not via the standard List Setting interface is beyond me (or: it does exist and it's just me who is missing it...)

Caviat: It gives the path only from a certain point in the full URL (in my case: instead of "http:///sites/MySite/..." it gives "/sites/MySite/..." ). So if I want to send a "clean" path to someone (without the extra garbage in the address-bar URL) I still have to copy the path, then attach the prefix. What a great design. :-o

Michael